# Sort an excel matrix by column headers, from an array of those headers

Tags: arrays, excel, matrix

I feel like this should be something you can easily do in excel, but I can't seem to figure out how to.  What I would like to do is sort a matrix of values on their names, but not alphabetically or by value or anything, but by another row of names.  For instance:

```
Headers    A B C
Val1       1 2 3
Val2       4 5 6

sorted_headers C B A
```

And i would like the matrix to be:

```
Headers    C B A
Val1       3 2 1
Val2       6 5 4
```

Based on the other row "sorted_headers", I know I could program something to do this, but it just seems like something you should be able to do without a line of VBA.

Thanks!

Comment: No, Excel isn't designed to do this. You're teetering on the edge of needing to use a database.

Comment: Hmm.  That is rather annoying.  I suppose I can write something quickly in perl or ruby, but I really wanted to keep it all in excel.  I dislike programming in VBA, and avoid it if I can...

Comment: You could add a last row to your table which uses MATCH() to get the position of each header in your "sorted" list, then sort left to right on that row.

Comment: @tim-williams Yes!  That worked perfectly, thank you!  I'm not sure how to mark a comment as the answer, but that certainly solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1. Add an additional row to your table which uses MATCH() to get the position of each header in your "sorted" list
2. Use the regular Excel sorting functionality to sort left to right on that row

Answer (score 0):

When you select Sort from the ribbon or after right-clicking with the sort range selected, choose Custom Sort, select Options, and set sort to Left to right. Then set the sort rows you want to use.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it, I don't want to change the orientation of the "sorted_headers" row.  I want the other columns to be ordered *by* it.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? It shouldn't change the orientation of the (data) row headers, only their order. Just as you set the columns you want to sort by when sorting rows, with the "Sort left to right", you set the rows you want to sort by when sorting columns. For me, this produces the result set you specified.

Comment: Ah, the problem might be because the example I used simply reverses the order.  I would like it to be able to sort *by* that row.  I'm using office 2010.  Can you confirm your method works if you change it to something like "B A C"?  This does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Hmm. When I use "B A C" for the headers, with the sort option set to "Left to right" and and the sort order for the header row set to "A to Z", I get the columns sorted "A B C".

Comment: Oh, I see what is going on.  This does seem to work in the example.  However, if you use headers which are more complex, this will not hold.  For example if the "sorted_headers" were of values "Rh4 7169 B617"  and the column headers currently had "7169 Rh4 B617" this method won't work.  It does work in the specific example I gave, but won't work as a general solution.

Comment: You should get the same sort order as if the headers & data were transposed and rows were sorted, i.e., numbers, numbers as text, keyboard special characters, and case-insensitive alpha.